# left join count ignore left table column from counting

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables ...first has `order_id`, `order_status`, and `user_id` .... second table has `order_id` ,and `product_id`, `product_quantity` like below

1st table

```
    order_id | order_status | user_id
    ----------------------------
    1        | 5            | 2
    2        | 1            | 1
    3        | 5            | 1
    4        | 5            | 1
```

2nd Table

```
order_id | product_id | quantity
----------------------------
1        | 200        | 4
2        | 201        | 2
2        | 200        | 1
2        | 207        | 4
3        | 201        | 1
3        | 200        | 6
4        | 201        | 8
```

I want to get

```
    user_id | Total_orders | quantity
    ----------------------------
    1       | 2            | 15
    2       | 1            | 4
```

get user_id where order_status = 5 and sum(quantity) group by user_id

**MY TRY**

```
SELECT h.user_id
     , COUNT(IF(h.order_status = 5,1,0)) AS total_orders
     , SUM(o.quantity) AS quantity 
  FROM table1 h 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table2 o  
    ON o.order_id = h.order_id 
 WHERE h.order_status = 5 
 GROUP 
    BY h.user_id
```

But, it gives me result counting all instance of order_id in left table like ... total orders of user_id 1 with status 5 are 2 but my query return 3 as count (`order_id`) bcz there are 3 instance of passed orders by user id 1.

Any suggestions or solutions ...i am stuck since long :(

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to count the number of *distinct* occurrences of `order_id`:

```
SELECT h.user_id, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT h.order_id) AS total_orders, 
       SUM(o.quantity) AS quantity 
FROM table1 h 
LEFT JOIN table2 o ON o.order_id=h.order_id 
WHERE h.order_status = 5 
GROUP BY h.user_id
```

Also, using `IF` function inside `COUNT` like this:

```
COUNT(IF(h.order_status = 5,1,0)) AS total_orders
```

makes no sense since `h.order_status` is *always* equal to 5, due to the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE h.order_status = 5
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/849ad5/3)